# Youtube API query returns null

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, google-api, google-api-client

The youtube search query for "Kanye West Amazing" should return several youtube links. However, the youtube query through the api is returning null (from console.log):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Vidify</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Add a button for the user to click to initiate auth sequence -->
    <button id="authorize-button" style="visibility: hidden">Authorize</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var clientId = '591751286145-ktngvf2s76uiuuevan6mo1fft0kchl8l.apps.googleusercontent.com';

      var apiKey = 'AIzaSyB0mteDV5vDKFR-iAv4Fx4OC2gp1Yhqe9U';

      var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube';

      function handleClientLoad() {
        console.log('API key provided - authorizing client...');
        // Step 2: Reference the API key
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
        gapi.auth.init(checkAuth);
      }

      function checkAuth() {
        console.log('entered checkAuth - authorizing...');
        setTimeout(function() { 
            console.log("requesting auth");
            gapi.auth.authorize({ 
                client_id: clientId, 
                scope: scopes, 
                response_type:'token',
                immediate: true 
            }, handleAuthResult); 
        }, 100); 
      }

      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        console.log('received authResult');
        var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          console.log("auth. successful");
          authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
          makeApiCall();
        } else {
          console.log('auth failed.');
          authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
        }
      }

      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        // Step 3: get authorization to use private data
        console.log('retry');
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
        return false;

      }

      // Load the API and make an API call.  Display the results on the screen.
        function makeApiCall() {
            console.log("loaded client");
            gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
            // Step 4: Load the Google+ API
            gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
                console.log('youtube API loaded...');
                // Step 5: Assemble the API request
                var qVar = "Kanye West Amazing"
                // changed. added: type
                var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
                    type: 'video',
                    part: 'id',
                    q: qVar
                });
                // Step 6: Execute the API request
                request.execute(function(resp) {

                    console.log(resp);
                    var vid = document.createElement('vid');
                    vid.value = resp.items[0].id.videoId;
                    console.log(vid.value);
                    var youtube_url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=";
                    youtube_url += vid.value;
                    youtube_url += "&rel=0";
                    window.open(youtube_url);
                });
              });
          }
    </script>

    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=makeApiCall"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

So I'm actually trying to run this from within the spotify desktop application. The spotify apps system lets me load an index.html from within the "spotify browser." Here are the errors I'm getting now:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setApiKey' of undefined
>
> index.html:63 makeApiCall index.html:63 (anonymous function)
>
> client.js?onload=makeApiCall:6 fa client.js?onload=makeApiCall:1 b
>
> client.js?onload=makeApiCall:6 v.(anonymous function)
>
> client.js?onload=makeApiCall:6 H.(anonymous function)
>
> client.js?onload=makeApiCall:6 (anonymous function) cb=gapi.loaded_0:1
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
> cb=gapi.loaded_0:6
>
> _.J cb=gapi.loaded_0:6 (anonymous function) cb=gapi.loaded_1:6 (anonymous function) client.js?onload=makeApiCall:4 Z
>
> client.js?onload=makeApiCall:6 ua client.js?onload=makeApiCall:4 E
>
> client.js?onload=makeApiCall:5 b client.js?onload=makeApiCall:6
>
> v.(anonymous function) client.js?onload=makeApiCall:6 H.(anonymous
> function) client.js?onload=makeApiCall:6 (anonymous function)
> cb=gapi.loaded_1:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may have done your nesting incorrectly; you are running the request.execute call outside the gapi.client.load function's callback, so the actual request itself isn't created when it tries to run (the gapi client loads the APIs asynchronously). If instead you tried this:

```
  function makeApiCall() {
    // Step 4: Load the Google+ API
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
        console.log('youtube API loaded...');
        // Step 5: Assemble the API request
        var qVar = "Kanye West Amazing"
        // changed. added: type
        var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            type: 'video',
            part: 'id',
            q: qVar
        });
        // Step 6: Execute the API request
        request.execute(function(resp) {
          document.getElementById('vid').value = resp.items[1].id.videoId;
          console.log('saved video id successfully');
        });
      });
  }
```

Then it should wait and do the request only after the API code is loaded. This also assumes, of course, that you have an element with id "vid" (which your sample code didn't have).

As far as the scopes go, you don't need them for this particular call, as it's not one that needs to be authenticated (i.e. you can just run MakeApiCall() without authorization). However, if you'll be doing other things later that need authorization, it is functioning properly so you could just as easily leave it in.

Comment: I'll try the appropriate changes later tonightand let you know if this works. I did forget to make the DOM element for 'vid'!

Comment: So after making those changes, it looks like gapi is not loading the youtube api. More precisely, 'youtube API loaded...' is never getting printed to console. Is there anything else I'm supposed to do before trying to load the api?

Comment: So in other words, perhaps makeApiCall() isn't being called from your auth logic? To eliminate that as a possibility, try this: in your makeApiCall() function, define your API key variable (just the key) and have this call ... gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey); ... right at the beginning. Then change your script element callback to call that function straight away (ignoring the auth stuff):     <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=makeApiCall"></script> If this works, you know the search is properly working and the error is in triggering the call from your auth routine.

Comment: So i made a lot of progress after I realized the my origin was null (google API's don't work on localhost). So I added index.html to xampp and now I'm getting the following error: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "about:blank".

Comment: Do you happen to have the 'disconnect' chrome extension (or another privacy extension) installed? They sometimes can block the loading of the gapi client.

Comment: Thank you so much! I still needed to add the setAPIkey part

Comment: Yeah I had to disable Disconnect.

Comment: Hi jim, could you take another look at the OP. I'm getting an error a little more specific to my project now.